# On which Stack Exchange site should I ask for feedback about my projects?

Tags: discussion, questions

I'm not talking about bugs or general programming questions, but more like feedback on the style, features, performance, etc of what I write.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

For feedback on already working code, you ought to consider [Code Review.SE](http://codereview.stackexchange.com): that's their specialty.

Check [their FAQ](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/faq) look around at [their questions](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions) to see if there's a match for the type of question you want to ask. If you're still in doubt, try asking about your question on [their meta-discussion site](http://meta.codereview.stackexchange.com).

For higher-level, conceptual questions about programming design, your question might work well on [Programmers.SE](http://programmers.stackexchange.com). If you are interested in high-level feedback, please make sure your question is specific enough to be answerable (e.g., no "Should I use two spaces or three spaces when indenting my code?" or "What should I name my variable?" questions).